# Visual Studio Code debugger doesn't stop at breakpoints

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

https://github.com/discord-bot-tutorial/Community-Discord-BOT 
The c# debugger for vscode doesn't stop at breakpoints with this specific project. I have tried creating a new project with
`dotnet new console
dotnet restore` 
which worked correctly and I tried it with another project I created in Visual Studio Community 2017 which worked exactly as it should too.

launch.json and tasks.json
https://gist.github.com/M4N1/daff738de1d5cbcf8cf3fdc461c3a83c

**Update**

I just tried the same thing on Ubuntu 18.04 (instead of win10) where it worked perfectly fine with the same version of vscode (1.28.1).

Comment: Running the project in Release Mode? How do the breakpoints appear Solid filled Spheres or Hollow (ouline only) - later would mean dll & pdb/code is out of sync.

Comment: The sphere is hollow.

Comment: Mouse hover that Sphere and it will tell you the problem. Your DLL (Binaries) are not in sync with the Source Code/PDB file. Clean-Rebuild the project. Then check the modified datetime of both the dll and corresponding pdb file.

Comment: It says "Unverified breakpoint"

Comment: Any of these help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510655/unverified-breakpoint-in-visual-studio-code-with-chrome-debugger-extension

Comment: Is that all it says? https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+code+Unverified+breakpoint

Comment: "Unverified breakpoint" is all it says and @PrateekShrivastava no none of these helped.

Comment: @ManuelMoser - Works for me in VS2017

Comment: In Visual Studio everything is working fine. The problem is Visual Studio Code.

Comment: This is so horrible. It happens to me all the time with no solution and for no apparent reason. MacOS 13.1. C and C++ (not C#)

Answer (score 8):

I use this configuration and work only if I insert this two line

```
// "stopOnEntry": true
// "justMyCode": false

{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Debug Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "justMyCode": false
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Those last two lines are super useful 

Comment: "justMyCode" is an invalid option. I get a compiler warning with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have upgraded your **.Net Core SDK** recently, just update **netcoreappX.X**

```
 "program": "${workspaceFolder}/CommunityBot/bin/Debug/netcoreappX.X/CommunityBot.dll"
```

in `launch.json` file.
Check your .Net Core SDK version by `dotnet --version`

Answer (score 1):

In  VSCode 1.20 and 1.21 does not allow you to hit breakpoints. VSCode 1.18 works fine

If you are using VSCode 1.21  set the `outFiles` parameter in your launch config

**Workaround -**
Try Deactivate then reactive breakpoints after debugging has started, Or, right click the breakpoints pane and "Reapply all breakpoints".

Comment: Didn't work.
Additional info:
Version: 1.28.1 (system setup)
Commit: 3368db6750222d319c851f6d90eb619d886e08f5
Date: 2018-10-11T18:13:53.910Z
Electron: 2.0.9
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
Architecture: x64

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, I added `debug` mode to the argument list in the `launch.json`

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/cs-scrapes.dll",


        "args": ["run",
            "debug"

        ],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopAtEntry": false
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it helped to start debugging through the toolbar (by clicking) instead of pressing F5.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there is a warning in debug console saying

> To allow this breakpoint to be hit: Add '"requireExactSource": false' to launch.json and restart debugging

And that's what I did. After that, breakpoints were triggered properly. Here's my `launch.json`:

```js
"configurations": [
        {

            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/###/##.dll",
            "args": [
            ],
            "requireExactSource": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/####",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        }
    ]
```