# Debug mode not stop at breakpoint when VS Code workspace is under Python installation directory and justMyCode is true

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to learn how to use break points.

As you can see in below screenshot, the program didn't stop at break point and the variables window is empty.

I press the button in orange circle. I have also tried press F5 Start debugging. Both have same result.

What could be the problem?

[image]

Here is my code. There is no error message. The program run from line 1 to line 9 without error.

```
a = 33
b = 200
if b>a:
    print("b is larger than b")

c = 1000
d = 9999
if d>c:
    print("d is larger than c")
```

Here is my debug configuration launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, not an image.

Comment: Could you post a higher resolution image?

Comment: Also, could you mark the button you pressed to start the debug mode on the image?

Comment: I could not reproduce the behaviour on my VS Code (v.1.85.1 on Ubuntu). It could be something related to launch.json file. See, for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/75978382/3015186

Comment: Do you see any warnings in the Debug Console? Check also the docs here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Comment: There is no warning in debug console. Also I added my launch.json configuration file to my post. I installed my python at non-default path. I wonder is it causing problem.

Comment: use `F5` to start launch config, NEVER use these top-right buttons

Comment: @rioV8 FYI pretty sure you're seeing it wrong? that button encircled at the top right of the screenshot _is_ the debug view's run button. they just moved their run/debug view to the secondary/auxiliary sidebar.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Include the version number of your Python extension. 3) Include the Python interpreter you have selected in VS Code, and the output you see when you run that interpreter in the commandline with `--version`

Comment: @starball Yep. Looking at the file paths, he has created a VSC workspace directory with the `test.py` file INSIDE the python interpreter directory with the `python.exe`. First place the VSC workspace OUTSIDE the python interpreter directory. Your file is seen as part of the python libs, it is INSIDE the python interpreter directory, you have the `justMyCode:true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the file paths, you have created a VSC workspace directory with the `test.py` file INSIDE the python interpreter directory with the `python.exe`.

First place the VSC workspace OUTSIDE the python interpreter directory.

Your file `test.py` is seen as part of the python libs, it is INSIDE the python interpreter directory, you have the `justMyCode:true`

Comment: Thank you. After change the directory, the debug mode is working.

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the stop in the loop line. If you want to check the values before it enters and does the whole loop, you need to place it in the line before, if not, you are stopping the debug in the loop exit, and you program ends when your loop ends.

Comment: I have tried added breakpoint on every line. The debugger just don't stop on any. I guess I missed some configuration in my visual studio code.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the true cause but I found a workaround.

I create a Jupyter Notebook (test.ipynb) then copy my code to one of the cell. Then I press "Debug Cell" as in below screen capture. Then the debug mode and breakpoints are working as expected.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer your question and shouldn't be posted as an answer

Comment: @possum I think this is fine. there is no law here that says that workarounds are definitively illegitimate answers. in fact, many people find workarounds useful.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you create a working area in the Python directory.

[image]

Modifying *launch.json* `justMyCode` value to `false` can make debugging stop at the breakpoint.

But the correct approach should be to create a working area **outside** the Python directory.

Comment: what's the point of posting this? it says essentially the same thing as riov8's answer post.