# How to display current values of VS Code's predefined variables (such as "${workspaceFolder}" or "${fileWorkspaceFolder}")?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am facing an issue with VS code debugger while trying to debug some angular typescript source code, and I think the reason is that some of those [VS Code Variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) have the wrong value - as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52391649/1016343).

I'd like to follow that advice, but I see no way how to query the VS code variables (e.g. display the current values of these variables for my project).

One of these variables is

> ${workspaceFolder}

They are used in VS code's config files, for this example in the `launch.json` file.

Do you know if there is a way to display those values? For example, log the values or show them in an alert window would just be sufficient for me to troubleshoot it.

Comment: With VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020), you will have [`${fileWorkspaceFolder}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64870853/6309).

Comment: @VonC - Thank you for the hint, and the link!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Old answer:

There may be a better way but you could run a

```
//  "preLaunchTask": "Echo vars" in your debug launch like:

{
    "name": "Chrome : Launch with sourcemaps",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://localhost:3000",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "runtimeArgs": [
    "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
    ],
    "preLaunchTask": "Echo vars"
},
```

in your launch task and then in tasks.json add:

```
{
   "label": "Echo vars",
   "command": "echo",
   "args": [
     "${env:USERNAME}",
     "workspaceFolder = ${workspaceFolder}"
   ],
   "type": "shell"
},
```

Those values will be echoed to the terminal.

---

---

**EDIT**:

Because a later version of vscode now supports sending variables to the terminal this **simpler** keybinding will print out values in the terminal:

```
[
    {
        "key":  "alt+q",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
            // "text": "echo ${env:USERNAME}",  // this works
            "text" : "echo file = '${file}' : workspaceFolder = '${workspaceFolder}'\u000D"
        }
    }
]
```

then <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> prints out the values.

The `\u000D` at the end is just a return.

Answer (score 3):

Open C:\Users\**your user name**\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\keybindings.json

Copy the data object below and add it to keybindings.json. Use whatever predefined variables you want.

```
{
    "key":  "alt+q",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text" : "echo file = '${file}' : workspaceFolder = '${workspaceFolder}'\u000D"
    }
}
```

Type alt+q in terminal to see results.