# VSCode: How do I find what my workspace folder is

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a simple command that will tell me what my workspace folder is? I tried `${workspaceFolder}` in the terminal but that didn't work.

Comment: Do you need that for further CLI processing or just to see it?

Comment: Just to see it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53485115/how-to-display-current-values-of-vs-codes-predefined-variables-such-as-work/53486166#53486166

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alternatives that currently come to my mind:

1.) If you want to see the workspace folder in the titlebar, you could adjust `window.title` setting (workspace or user settings):

```
"window.title": "${dirty}${activeEditorShort}${separator}${folderPath}${separator}${appName}"
```

Multiple variables can be used here - see [Defaults](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings) -> window.title. `${folderPath}` works best for me, if you prefer the absolute workspace path.

2.) Define a task that can print your workspace folder at the terminal:

```
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo ${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
```

3.) `File -> save as workspace` should actually show the current workspace folder (seems to be not consistent with Windows/Mac though)

4.) Just open the terminal and look at your `cwd`. I am not sure, if all terminals default to the workspace folder.

Comment: The first method works. Regarding the third, I'm on a Mac and I have "Save As..." and "Save Workspace As..." but neither of these show the current workspace folder when I select them.

Comment: OK, good hint. I am on windows, does seem to work there.  4.) possibility would be to just open terminal and see the cwd. I am not sure, if that fits for all terminals, but I'll add it with reservation.

Comment: workspaceRoot still works for now but it was deprecated long ago, see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/commit/797ca8054fe7e9b3bf812d2b366631e12c11b90e and no mention of it in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference.  Don't use `workspaceRoot`.

Answer (score 7):

[VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/bcb958b02f6b6a5ef883ce3af96f0cfd56c3a816/release-notes/v1_52.md#new-variables-for-launchjson-and-tasksjson) will simplify that use case.

Before:

```
/ws
   /.vscode
        launch.json
/proj_a
   /scr
/proj_b
   /scr
/proj_c
   /scr
/proj_d
   /scr
```

> Where `/ws` and `/proj_*` are all folders added to create the multi folder workspace.
> But `${workspaceFolder}` always is `/ws`

`${workspaceFolder:proj_a}` is possible but not convenient, when you have a debug configuration in `/ws/.vscode/launch.json` that uses `${file}` and you want to be able to use this configuration on all files in your multi-root setup.
And in order to establish the correct working directory for your debuggee you need a way to derive the workspace folder path from `${file}`.

Introducing `${fileWorkspaceFolder}`.

With VSCode 1.52, see:

- [issue 84162](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84162): "Get the workspace folder of the current file "
- [issue 108907](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108907): "Multi root workspace - Variable for the current file's workspace directory"
- [commit 876d1f0](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/876d1f09cc242f00ffcbec9766d13ce9503f90a1): introduce new variable `${fileWorkspaceFolder}`

That will complement the [Predefined variables examples](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables-examples).