# How to get folderpath name of currently opened file in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular7, angular8, vscode-extensions

I have opened multiple angular projects in visual studio code and 
i am trying to get cuttenlty opened file's project folder path inside my extension. But I am not getting the correct path . Anyone know please help to find the solution.

Below script only will work if I open single angular project in VS Code but how do for if I open multiple project folders.

extension.js:

```js
exports.activate = context => {
    const mymodules = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.search', () => {

    var rootUri = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri;
    var folderPathNameOfCurrentlyOpenedFile=rootUri.fsPath;  // currently opened file's project folder path[Opened single project]

    ...
}
```

Comment: With VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020), you will have [`${fileWorkspaceFolder}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64870853/6309) which could help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the workspace folder from which the currently active document is, use this:

```js
vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.search', () => {

  if (vscode.window.activeTextEditor) {

    let workspaceFolder = vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri);
    let rootUri = workspaceFolder.uri;
  }
}
```

The `workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(...)` function finds the workspace folder, where the document belongs.

Comment: Tried but not working..I have asked to get currently opened file's angular project folderpath..

Comment: You have any idea?

Comment: I think you should add the [angular] tag to attract attention of the Angular people.

Comment: I have added like angular 7 and 8