# Unable to connect to SSH bitnami GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I was able to connect to SSH until a few hours ago. However, suddenly I am receiving the following error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

I am not sure what might have happened.

One thing that I notice is if I go to "Metadata > SSH", I see keys have an expiry for todays date. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Did you open the SSH port (22) in the Google Cloud Security Group for this Compute Engine instance?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to connect using [Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcetools) method, it is possible that an extension or your AntiVirus is blocking the connection as mentioned in this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54619817/how-to-fix-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-could-not-establish-connection-receivi)

I would try using a different SSH method described in [third-party tools](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools) section or with a different browser